# PowerShell Remoting - Broken session state

Tags: powershell

I use PowerShell remoting to run CMCB Windows patching. As the monthly fat OS update takes up to an hour, I periodically monitor the progress through PowerShell remoting session. I create the session object first, which is used for subsequent invoke-command invocations.

The problem is, out of 100 servers on average, 1 server randomly fails in this 1 hour window whilst running this operation. The error logged points to broken PS session.

I was wondering if there is a clever way to automatically check the $session.state every time I use the $session in invoke-command. If it's not 'Opened', I want this auto code to create new $session object and use that new $session instead.

I am particularly thinking in terms of property getters or may be adding some sort of ScriptProperty to the session object using add-member. But I have been unsuccessful.

Are you able to help? Thanks.

**Update:**

I am trying the below code but not working as I expect

```
$Server = 'servername'
$Session = try { New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -ErrorAction Stop } catch {}

$Session | Add-Member -Name SessionValid -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
    return  $(if($this.State -ne 'Opened'){  try { New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -ErrorAction Stop } catch {}} else { $this })
}

while($true){
    try { Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { $pid } } catch {}
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

Comment: Did you try using [Disconnect-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/disconnect-pssession?view=powershell-7.4) to avoid having to keep an open session for all that time?  This leaves the remote commands running and you can re-connect any time to check progress/get results.

Comment: Probably an option but I have to monitor the progress once every 30 seconds  as there are smaller updates taking only 2-3 minutes. So it may not address the underlying issue.

Comment: "I am trying the below code but not working as I expect" - tell us _how_ it's not working. Are you getting errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: It says session state broken when i restart wsman on target midstream, where as I was expecting it to seamlessly continue and show the new wsmanprovhost pid

Comment: I tried adding a breakpoint for the scriptproperty code but it doesn't break at that line. Looks as though that custom property never gets read. Os is it a ISE red-herring?